# Ejecutar codigo php a partir de post enviado con funcion Cur con url

Tags: php

> Estoy tratando de ejecutar el codigo (test.php)enviando un POST ($envio). A tra-
>   vez de una url con Cur pero al ejecutarlo no abre el archivo test.php.

```
i<?php
$url="http://localhost/ej1/test.php";
$envio ='nombre='.urlencode('Miguel').'&entrar='.urlencode("Aceptar");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$envio);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$respuesta= curl_exec($ch);
$error= curl_error($ch);
if($respuesta===false){
    echo "error";
    echo curl_getinfo($ch);
}else{
echo ("EXITO");
}
curl_close($ch);
```

?>

Comment: ¿Muestra algún error? Prueba esta comprobación y di si imprime algo: `if(curl_errno($ch)){ echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch); }`

Comment: Lo agregue y no muestra error.

Comment: Depura la respuesta: `var_dump($respuesta);`

Comment: Al parecer no es lo que yo esperaba me aparece esto: C:\wamp64\www\ej1\sms_mig2.php:16:string '' (length=0)

Comment: La respuesta en sí no parece ser errónea, sino que devuelve una cadena vacía. Revisa qué respondes en el archivo al que haces la petición `cURL` a ver si hay alguna anomalía o si no estás devolviendo nada realmente. Si todo está bien allí, revisa las respuestas a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14679886/5587982).